# Elasticsearch 7.11 Python Scan is infinite

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

```
page = helpers.scan(
        c, query=q,
        index=idx,
        scroll='5m',
        size=1000,
    )

    i = 0
    for hit in page:
        i = i + 1
        if i % 1000 == 0 and i > 0:
            print("dump finished %i items" % i)
        yield {"_source": hit['_source'], "_id": hit['_id']}
```

The problem is that this loop scan never ends and the last batch of results is probably being looped infinite times.
I dump the data into a file and the first entries are present 1 time. The last entries are being written repeatedly and the loop keeps going.

Not sure if it's a bug in my code or in the library.

Update 1:

```
    slices = [
        delayed(iterate_slice)(1, es_host, idx, slices, q, size, logger_name)
    ]

    return db.from_delayed(slices)
```

then iterate_slice has the following code:

```
    page = helpers.scan(
        c, query=q,
        index=idx,
        scroll='5m',
        size=10000,
    )

    i = 0
    for hit in page:
        i++
        if i % 1000 == 0 and i > 0:
            print("dump finished %i items" % i)
        yield {"_source": hit['_source'], "_id": hit['_id']}
```

Comment: How many does do you have? What does `print(len(list(page)))` print? Where's the code that actually (re)writes the file? Sorry but that code snippet is not sufficient for the community to help you.

Comment: @JoeSorocin the thing is that the lines get dumped to the file. it contains the following data `first 1000 lines, then the next 1000 lines, ... so on ..., last 1000 lines, last 1000 lines, last 1000 lines .... ` It repeats the last page infinite times.

Comment: print(len(list(page))) returns 1583471